# Using a Google Sheet as Database for Prototyping

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using a google sheet to prototype an app i make.

I have an App Script in which i get some data from an API.
When i get the JSON in my App the values which are coming from the API are always on the state "Loading...".

I'm using https://github.com/giladaya/get-sheet-done

I have set up a timer, so that the sheet refreshes every minute.

Normally i would say this just does not work, but i know that it worked before.

Did you worked before with something like that or do you know what the reason for my issue is?

This is my appscript code:

```
function ccprice(index, currency) {
var url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var json = response.getContentText();
var data = JSON.parse(json);


  var priceval = {"USD" : data[index].price_usd, "BTC" : data[index].price_btc,
                  "24h_volume_usd" : data[index]["24h_volume_usd"], 
                  "market_cap_usd" : data[index].market_cap_usd, "available_supply" : data[index].available_supply, 
                  "total_supply" : data[index].total_supply, "percent_change_1h" : data[index].percent_change_1h, 
                  "percent_change_24h" : data[index].percent_change_24h, "percent_change_7d" : data[index].percent_change_7d,
                  "last_updated" : data[index].last_updated }


  var price = parseFloat(priceval[currency])

return price
}

function ccname(index) {
var url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var json = response.getContentText();
var data = JSON.parse(json);

  var name = {"name" : data[index].name }


  var name = name.name

return name
}
```

Comment: Google Apps Script triggers have quotas. Check it out if your triggers didn't consume all your quota. See [Maximum run time of Google script per user or per account](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36804160/1595451)

Comment: I copied the sheet data in another sheet with app scripts. Solved my problem.